# Why client does not instantly return from client method?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

client method

```
Meteor.methods({
  insertPost: function(data) {
    console.log('client')
    Posts.insert(data, function(err, ret) {
      console.log('client insert end')
    });
  },
});
```

server method

```
Meteor.methods({
  insertPost: function(data) {
    console.log('server')
    Meteor._sleepForMs(200000);
    Posts.insert(data, function(err, ret) {
      console.log('server insert end')
    });
  },
});
```

client submit

```
  'click #save': function(e) {
    // data = ....    
    Meteor.call('insertPost', data, function(error) {
      Router.go('/');
    });
  },
```

Why does client stuck at form page, instead of instantly going to '/'.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://www.reddit.com/r/Meteor/comments/2wcvz1/where_do_i_put_my_meteor_methods/ You could keep your code DRY by defining methods in /lib instead of having slightly different versions in /client and /server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the meteor documentation about it.

> Calling methods on the client defines stub functions associated with
>   server methods of the same name. You don't have to define a stub for
>   your method if you don't want to. In that case, method calls are just
>   like remote procedure calls in other systems, and you'll have to wait
>   for the results from the server.
>
> If you do define a stub, when a client invokes a server method it will
>   also run its stub in parallel. On the client, the return value of a
>   stub is ignored. Stubs are run for their side-effects: they are
>   intended to simulate the result of what the server's method will do,
>   but without waiting for the round trip delay. If a stub throws an
>   exception it will be logged to the console.